# inssert <br> for the 1st comma & replace all the dot with <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert `<br>` for the first comma, and for every dot (period)?

```js
<script>
var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.replace(/\./g,'.<br/>');   
$('.test').html(result);
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Hi,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to replace first comma, you can use something like this:

```
var test = $('.test').text();
first_comma=test.indexOf(','); //return first comma position
test=test.replace(test.charAt(first_comma),',<br>') //replace it
var result = test.replace(/\./g,'.<br>');   
$('.test').html(result);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4jgyj98c/

Comment: Thank you so much - have a lovely day

Answer (score 3):

you can call `replace` again:

```
var result = test.replace(/\./g,'.<br/>').replace(',', '<br/>');
```

Comment: i don't think OP wants to replace the comma with a <br>, i think they want to insert a <br> after the first comma? (i could be wrong, that's just how i interpreted it)

Comment: if this is the case, just use `.replace(',', ',<br/>')` instead

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the jquery part after loading jquery, and also to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var test = $('.test').text();
  var result = test.replace(/\./g,'.<br/>');
  // var result = test.split('.').join('.<br/>');
  $('.test').html(result);
})
```

will be a good prectice. so put all your code into this function.
I also mention another way to do it. you can try that as well. both will do the same.

Comment: this doesn't insert a <br> for the 1st comma

Comment: if you need <br> at comma and dot both then you can try this
"test.replace(/\./g,'.<br>').replace(/\,/g,',<br>');"
or
"test.split('.').join('.<br/>').split(',').join(',<br/>');"